# capture image with camera - Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera-intent

Im trying to capture image with camera, i do it in this way :

**start camera :**

```
public void startPhotoTaker() {

            // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "cs_" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
            mLastPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mLastPhoto);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE);
        }
```

**onActivityResult :**

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE) {
                /**
                 Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                 mediaScanIntent.setData(mLastPhoto);
                 this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                 */

                File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mLastPhoto));
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                        this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, final Uri uri) {

                                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        handleSendDelete(mLastPhoto, "image/*", true);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
            }
```

The problem is when i back to the app its colose with error ! 
its app logcat :

```
03-03 13:02:22.851: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1808): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {info.guardianproject.otr.app.im/info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.ChatViewActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4, result=-1, data=null} to activity {info.guardianproject.otr.app.im/info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.ChatViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2472)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=4, result=-1, data=null} to activity {info.guardianproject.otr.app.im/info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.ChatViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2431)
        ... 12 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.ChatViewActivity.getRealPathFromURI(ChatViewActivity.java:424)
        at info.guardianproject.otr.app.im.app.ChatViewActivity.onActivityResult(ChatViewActivity.java:336)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
        ... 13 more
```

I debug my app and i think this field : mLastPhoto is null ! but i dont know why ? it has value when i start the camera !

UPDATE :

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error inside getRealPathFromURI() post the code for that.

Comment: add the method to question :)

Comment: your code is working at my end, post the code of handleSendDelete()

Comment: You have a file path string and make an uri out of it. Then later you try to reclaim that file path from that uri. It is much simpler to save that file path string and use it later. Not that it solves your problem though. I think it depends on the used device that you have a null pointer. Which device is it? Try other devices.

Comment: the code working before i change the activity in this device @greenapps, but i will test it on emulator too

Comment: @Ishrat i can add it but the app stoped in this line :  File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(mLastPhoto));

Comment: Before you use mLastPhoto check if it is null. And don't continue if it is. Instead display a toast. You will find out that your activity went in onPause and onCreate . But this depends on the device. Which is it?

Comment: As said before don't use that uri. String filePath = null. filePath = photo.getAbsolutePath(); Then later on use filePath. But before use check for null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem in this way (Im not sure its the best way but worked for me) :

```
 @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("mLastPhoto", String.valueOf(mLastPhoto));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mLastPhoto = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("mLastPhoto"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `getRealPathFromURI()` method as below, it might be because of Deprecated `ManagedQuery()`,  Also please tell us which device you using it has enough space?

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

Also update your **onActivityResult** by updating  below two lines

```
 if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE) 
      {
       // Put your code here/.....
   }
  }
```

Comment: Im using huawei mediapad 7 tablet

Comment: have you tried by replacing getRealPathFromURI by answered method?

Comment: i checked resualt ok just doesnt add it in q

Comment: Please post line no. 424 in ChatViewActivity.java , also if you using in your activity onResume or onPause ? if yes please post the code.

Comment: Y.felzi you should use filePath and check for null. Your activity was killed by the os while the camera was active. This depends on the device.

Comment: can i avoid killing the activity ? i think this is the problem

Comment: Where  you killing the activity? remove that, Please post line no. 424 in ChatViewActivity.java

Comment: line 424 : Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);

Comment: the problem is mLastPhoto is null when i back from camera to app ! and i dont know why ! other error happening after this !

Comment: Is this resolved?? as pr the line no 424 you getting contentUri null

Comment: yeah ! contentUri is mLastPhoto , and its null

Comment: i check mLastPhoto for null the app doesnt crash now but it cant capture photo

Comment: `mLastPhoto is null when i back from camera to app ! and i dont know why ` . No? Please read carefully as you were told that already twice. The photo is captured though. Just look with gallery app.